# Unable to initialize a list collection in c #?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

Hello I do not know why it is impossible for me to complete my collection of objects declared just before.

**Here is my declaration a list of a list of objects.** (I want to store the list of objects in a reference list):

```
private List<List<Classes.instancedModel>> listInstance;
```

**I initialize in the constructor**

```
listInstance = new List<List<Classes.instancedModel>>();
```

**I initialize the first array of my list before completing my list in a loop** but i can not...

```
listInstance[0] = new List<Classes.instancedModel>();
listInstance[0].Add(new instancedModel(1, position_model_origin, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 1, Game));
```

But I will throw an exception of type: **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

Can someone explain to me how to declare two dynamic list and fill the fly as my example? with a list into a list

Comment: Which line is that error message from?

Comment: That looks OK so far. Have a look at the constructor of the `instancesModel` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A list isn't an array.** You may not access with the indexer unless there's at least an item.

```
listInstance[0] = new List<Classes.instancedModel>(); <--- NO!!

listInstance.Add(new List<Classes.instancedModel>()); <--- YES!!
```

Comment: So obvious. So well hidden. Well spotted! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for this issue so obvious. I put my question to resolve with your first answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is to add item to your list:

```
listInstance.Add(new List<Classes.instancedModel>()); //listInstance is List not an array
```

[`List<T>`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F6sh2ey19.aspx&ei=7rwTUdCkF8jJtAbnyoGgBg&usg=AFQjCNEDl4T3WgLBndZ1pncFdqEW4rkuog&sig2=7BOy_j5DYdIv53VTxfK_tw&bvm=bv.42080656,d.Yms) and [`Array`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.array.aspx&ei=Br0TUZr_C8jLswaBv4GICQ&usg=AFQjCNGHRGoMzf3IquzZAzpHwo0aEhdJDA&sig2=ssOvminZCXSHpFY0FOUeTg&bvm=bv.42080656,d.Yms) are not the same. When you call `instanceOfList[index]` you call [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). And if indexer will fail to find element at `index` will throw  `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for this explanation. I make it a point to your explanation advanced ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Add method first before using an index:

```
private List<List<instancedModel>> listInstance;
listInstance = new List<List<instancedModel>>();

listInstance.Add(new List<Classes.instancedModel>());

listInstance[0].Add(new instancedModel(1, position_model_origin, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 1, Game));
```

Answer (score 1):

listInstance[0] does not exist until you create it - you have only created the list, you haven't added anything to it.

```
var listInstance = new List<List<instancedModel>>();

listInstance.Add(new List<instancedModel> {
    new instancedModel(1, position_model_origin, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 1, Game)
});
```